# Can't export data using getStaticProps() - Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Hi I am trying to implement server side rendering with react and NextJS. I am trying to pull some information from an API that can use on my home page but I am running into some issues. for instance as seen in my code below,, "the property 'map' does not exist on type". My code is as follows:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Banner from '../components/Banner'

const Home: NextPage = (exploreData) => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Head>
        <title>Don Airbnb</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

    
      <Header/>
      {/*Banner*/}
      <Banner/>

      <main className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-8 sm:px-16">
        <section className="pt-6">
          <h2 className="text-4xl font-semibold pb-5">Explore Nearby</h2>

          {/* Pull data from a server - API endpoints */}
          {exploreData.map(item => {
            <h1>{item.location}</h1>
          })}
        </section>
      </main>

    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const exploreData = await fetch('https://links.papareact.com/pyp').then(res => res.json());
  return {
    props: {
      exploreData
    }
  }
}
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Server Error
Error: page / getStaticProps can not be attached to a page's component and must be exported from the page. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/gssp-component-member
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

your page components must be **Default exported** and aslo export  your `getStaticProps` before your page component

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const exploreData = await fetch('https://links.papareact.com/pyp').then(res => res.json());
  return {
    props: {
      exploreData
    }
  }
}
const Home: NextPage = (exploreData) => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Head>
        <title>Don Airbnb</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

    
      <Header/>
      {/*Banner*/}
      <Banner/>

      <main className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-8 sm:px-16">
        <section className="pt-6">
          <h2 className="text-4xl font-semibold pb-5">Explore Nearby</h2>

          {/* Pull data from a server - API endpoints */}
          {exploreData.map(item => {
            <h1>{item.location}</h1>
          })}
        </section>
      </main>

    </div>
  )
}
export default Home: NextPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the componennt also at the bottom like this

```
export default Home:NextPage;
```

And Try to use like this

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const exploreData = await fetch('https://links.papareact.com/pyp').then(res => res.json());
  return {
    props: {
      exploreData: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(exploreData))
    }
  }
}
```